# Nodejs protect resources for specific user

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs application + MongoDB,  implemented authentication with jwt correctly! And all work fine.

My question is how I can allow only specific user for some resources.

I don’t talk about role like admin or guest.

For example 3 users are registered for my app,
user 1 login and get token, theoretically user 1 can get data from any protected data with rule “user”, even though these data is not related for him.

I mean user 1 theoretically can make request with valid token and looking for data about user 2.

So what the best way to validate if resource is related for specific user?

Comment: Maybe include your code showing how you handle user-level auth now as a starting point?

Comment: Since a signed token is proof that it's the correct user,and you signed it when the user logged in (or signed up) when you had user/password, I would consider it safe to just put user-id in your token payload. Any tampering, like changing user-id and it wouldn't validate. After that you just `req.user = mongo.findById(...); next()` in your express middleware.

Comment: If you don't want to roll your own, check out [passports jwt strategy](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt) but even that is overkill really since they also suggest you just `User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.sub})`.